# TFS2012 build server not restoring NuGet packages from in-house repository

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild

I've set up an in-house NuGet repository (a shared folder on one of our servers), and have added it to the "Available Sources" list in the Visual Studio NuGet settings on my PC. I'm able to successfully install a package into my solution from this repository.

However on the TFS server the build is failing because it can't restore this particular package (message: "Unable to find version 'xxx' of package 'xxx'"). The solution is configured for "enable NuGet package restore", which works fine for packages installed via `nuget.org`. It's just not restoring the package from our internal repository.

Permissions on the repository folder/share are fine. What am I missing?

I'm guessing I have to configure Visual Studio's "available sources" on the TFS server too, but presumably these settings are user-specific? The build service runs as NETWORK SERVICE, so how can I configure NuGet for this user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your build to run as a specific account. you can then logon with that account and prove off all of these little snags.

depending on which way you are doing the NuGet restore, have you updated the targets file with the location of your local feed?

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' ">
        <!-- Package sources used to restore packages. By default, registered sources under %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config will be used -->
        <!-- The official NuGet package source (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/) will be excluded if package sources are specified and it does not appear in the list -->
        <!--
            <PackageSource Include="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
            <PackageSource Include="https://my-nuget-source/nuget/" />
        -->
      <PackageSource Include="http://MyLocalFeed/nuget/nuget"/>

    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work initially. I then realised the build server was running an old version of NuGet (2.2). After updating this to 2.8 it worked. I guess the older version didn't understand the multiple package source syntax in the NuGet.targets file.

Comment: @AndrewStephens correct, package restore started with NuGet 2.7

Answer (score 29):

You can add the source to a machine-wide config on the TFS build server and it will be included in the list of sources when doing package restores.

What I did was create a file `%ProgramData%\NuGet\Config\sources.config` that contained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="internal source" value="http://internal_server/nuget/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

The name of the file doesn't matter, it's the location of the file. Nuget picks up any .config files under that folder.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/NuGet-Config-File#NuGet_config_extensibility_point

**UPDATE 2016-11-18**
According to http://blog.nuget.org/20161121/introducing-nuget4.0.html (under breaking changes), VS 2017+ and NuGet 4.0+ changes the location of the machine-wide config folder to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config\`.

Comment: did you mean %ProgramData%\NuGet\Config\ (no space)?

Comment: We use TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2015 to our builds so I thought I wanted to edit the file C:\ProgramData\NuGet\Config\VisualStudio\14.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.config, but nope.  %ProgramData%\NuGet\Config\sources.config was the answer.

Comment: This was driving me insane.  My entries NuGet.Config (in C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\NuGet directory) were not being recognized (on my build server).  "nuget.exe sources list" now reports all my custom sources.